# Disconnected IoT devices using TF Lite

Tags: performance, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

My team is coordinating a system of IoT devices (which at times will run disconnected). Within these devices, we are building computer vision capabilities to further perform object tracking, multi-object identification, and picking up speech (STT).

We have determined that our models will need to 1) run locally 2) be able to run deep learning 3) be able to perform multiple tasks.

The model sizes are quite large for IoT devices, however we are examining all options in terms of determining the feasibility of the system.

Is this a problem that has come up before within the TF Lite community?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow lite has come up with solutions for these challenges.
TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers and requires a 32-bit platform. It has been tested extensively with many processors based on the Arm Cortex-M Series architecture.

The following development boards are supported for IOT projects:

- Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense
- SparkFun Edge
- STM32F746 Discovery kit
- Adafruit EdgeBadge
- Adafruit TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers Kit
- Adafruit Circuit Playground Bluefruit
- Espressif ESP32-DevKitC
- Espressif ESP-EYE

When it comes to running deep learning models there is already APIs available and models are trained to do object tracking and much more.
This is the link https://tfhub.dev/ where you can find pretrained models for each problem domain and run easily on the development boards mentioned above without having to think about model sizes.